Absolute positioning of TikZ drawing at edge of page
I am trying to position a simple filled polygon in the south west corner of the page.  I compile my file multiple times, as required when using the remember capability of TikZ and my figure is not exactly in the lower left corner.  It's about 1mm above the bottom of the page and 1mm to the right of the left side of the page.  This little shift appears in both the TexWorks document viewer and when I look at the output PDF file with the Adobe Reader.  Where is this shift being introduced in this MWE?
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,landscape]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[xshift=0.0in,yshift=0.0in,anchor=south west] at (current page.south west)
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue] (0.0in,0.0in) -- (6.0in,0.0in) -- (6.5in,1.5in) -- (0.0in,1.5in) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Never nest tikzpictures. Instead you can directly use page coordinates in your polygon:
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,landscape]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[blue] (current page.south west) -- +(6.0in,0.0in) -- +(6.5in,1.5in) -- +(0.0in,1.5in) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



With \AddToHook{shipout/background}
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,landscape]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}%<--- comment in the final document
\usepackage{lipsum}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}
    {%
        \put (0,-\paperheight){%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \fill[blue] (0.0in,0.0in) -- (6.0in,0.0in) -- (6.5in,1.5in) -- (0.0in,1.5in) -- cycle;
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        }
    }
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}


